# Multiple Apple ID accounts – can I delete one safely?

Tags: accounts

I have two Apple ID accounts and wish to remove one as it causes confusion with password issues. What problems will this cause if I delete this app from my iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue you might have is if you have purchased/downloaded apps, music or any content with that apple ID. You won't be able to update them or you will need to re-download them or purchase them again with the other ID in order to continue having updates.

The same applies with synced content via iCloud such as contacts, iCal, etc.

You just need to be sure that no content, apps or anything was synced or downloaded with that ID.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to set both to the same password, recovery email & rescue questions.

End of confusion.

This is especially true for those who have had their iTunes/mac.com/me.com identities from long before both could be used for the same things (like me;)
Drove me nuts trying to remember which was which until I set them up the same.

BTW, you can't actually delete an Apple ID, only stop using it.
Anything purchased under the old ID would need to be repurchased under the new one.